# Azure ADB2C: How to go back a orchestration step in user journey

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Is there a way to go back to a orchestration Step of user journey in Azure ADB2C custom policy.

For Example:
OrchestrationStep n: Collect user info - Address.
OrchestrationStep n+1: Collect user info - Date of birth and Prefered language.
OrchestrationStep n+2: Send token

Is there a way to go back from n+1 step to n step in this scenario?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot go backwards through a user journey.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it as stated in the other answer but you can use a [SubJourney](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/subjourneys) to transfer/call workflow steps to recreate your last step depending on preconditions.